# Prove limit of a function that goes from $\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ where $f(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{(1 + 4x)(1 + 6y)}-1}{2x + 3y}$. I have already computed such limit by fixing $y = 0$, and it turned out it went to 1, and therefore I suspect the whole limit does as well. But the problem is I'm stuck when trying to deal with the following expression $|\frac{\sqrt{(1 + 4x)(1 + 6y)}-1}{2x + 3y} -1|$. I have to bound it by an expression of the type $M || (x,y) ||$, however, I've got no clue on how to simplify the expression.

I don't know if it will help anyone get an idea, but the way I got the limit by fixing $y = 0$ was the following:

$\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{(1 + 4x)(1 + 6y)}-1}{2x + 3y} = \lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{(1 + 4x)}-1}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sqrt{(1 + 4x)}-1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{(\sqrt{(1 + 4x)}-1)(\sqrt{(1 + 4x)}+1)}{x(\sqrt{(1 + 4x)}+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{4x}{x(\sqrt{(1 + 4x)}+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{4}{\sqrt{(1 + 4x)}+1} = \frac{1}{2} * \frac{4}{2} = 1$

Comment: A usual trick is you multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{(1+4x)(1+6y)}+1,$ and you get: $$\frac{4x+6y+24xy}{2x+3y}\cdot \frac1{\sqrt{\cdot}+1}$$ where the square root term converges to $\frac12$ and the simpler part can be written: $$2+\frac{24xy}{2x+3y}.$$ So ou need to compute $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{2x+3y}$$

Comment: Note that $f$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb R^2\setminus(0,0).$ It likely does not converge, unless you bound $(x,y)$ so that $2x+3y$ is away from zero. Something like $x,y\geq0$ is probably okay.

Comment: For example, if $y=\epsilon/3$ and $x=-(\epsilon-\epsilon^3)/2,$ then $$\frac{xy}{2x+3y}=\frac{-\epsilon^2+\epsilon^4}{6\cdot \epsilon^3}=\frac{\epsilon}6-\frac1{6\epsilon}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit does not exist. Indeed, as you have already noted, along the line $y=0$ as $x\to 0^+$,
$$f(x,0)= \frac{\sqrt{1 + 4x}-1}{2x}=\frac{4x}{2x(\sqrt{1 + 4x}+1)} \to 1.$$
On the other hand, along the parabolic curve $2x+3y=x^2$, as $x\to 0^+$, we have that $y=\frac{-2x+x^2}{3}\to 0$ and
$$\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=\frac{(1 + 4x)(1 + 6y)-1}{(2x + 3y)(\sqrt{(1 + 4x)(1 + 6y)}+1)}
=\frac{2(2x+3y+12xy)}{(2x + 3y)(\sqrt{(1 + 4x)(1 + 6y)}+1)}\\
&=\frac{2(x^2+4x(-2x+x^2))}{x^2(\sqrt{(1 + 4x)(1 + 6y)}+1)}
=\frac{2(-7+4x)}{\sqrt{(1 + 4x)(1 + 6y)}+1}\to -7.
\end{align}$$
Since $f(x,y)$ has two different limits as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0 ,0 )$ along two different paths, the given limit does not exists.

Notice that parabolic curve $2x+3y=x^2$ passes through $(0,0)$ with tangent line $2x+3y=0$ which does not belong to the domain of $f$ (see also Thomas Andrews's comment above).